# How to traversal a js object and log the traversal paths?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Traversal of an object is easy, but I found it hard to figure out the traversal paths for myself.

For example, here we have data like below:

```
data = {
    a: 'A',
    b: {
        d: [
            'F',
            'G'
        ],
        e: 'D'
    },
    c: 'C'
}
```

I want to output the traversal paths like this:

```
['a']
['b', 'd', 0]
['b', 'd', 1]
['b', 'e']
['c']
```

How do I write the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function rec(currentObject, path) {
    if (typeof currentObject !== "string" && currentObject.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentObject.length; i += 1) {
            rec(currentObject[i], path.concat(i));
        }
    } else if (typeof currentObject === "object") {
        for (var item in currentObject) {
            rec(currentObject[item], path.concat(item))
        }
    } else {
        console.log(path);
    }
}

rec(data, []);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'a' ]
[ 'b', 'd', 0 ]
[ 'b', 'd', 1 ]
[ 'b', 'e' ]
[ 'c' ]
```

Comment: Your second output is `[ 'b', 'd', '0' ]`. What I wanted is `[ 'b', 'd', 0 ]`, the array path should present as a number.